# How to find bases for Kernal Of representation matrix of linear transformation with non standard bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

With standard bases Its kinda easy, because the representation matrix come easy and the calculation for the bases of keranl come from Ax=0,  
but when we change the bases to non standard bases and move to representation matrix of linear transformation, its kinda confusing 
if i have $ T:R^3[x] \to R^3[x] $  
and my bases $ B= \{(1+x),(1+x^2),(x+ x^2)\} $  
The represantation matrix with B base is:   
$$ \begin{pmatrix}2& 1&3 \\2&1&3\\ 2 & -3 &-1\end{pmatrix}=D $$

so my quistion is  to calculate the kernael using this matrix and B bases do i need to get the vector coordinates to the general vector from $R^3[x]$ using B bases and calculate or i dont need it?  
the coordinate vector of general vector using B is   
$$\begin{pmatrix}1/2(a+b-c)\\1/2(a-b+c)\\1/2(-a+b+c)\end{pmatrix}=[v]$$ 
by the defenition of kernal, as i understand, to calculare the kernal i need to do it:  
$$ \begin{pmatrix}2& 1&3 \\2&1&3\\ 2 & -3 &-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1/2(a+b-c)\\1/2(a-b+c)\\1/2(-a+b+c)\end{pmatrix} $$  
but i dont know why in lectures lessons i see the right answer is to calculate this way $Dx=0$: 
 $$ \begin{pmatrix}2& 1&3 \\2&1&3\\ 2 & -3 &-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix} $$  

and after solving i know i should to place and get the right bases 
But why i can/need do Dx=0 and not:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}2& 1&3 \\2&1&3\\ 2 & -3 &-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1/2(a+b-c)\\1/2(a-b+c)\\1/2(-a+b+c)\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: You can, but your book's method is shorter. Did you compare its final result with yours?

Comment: yes, it ineed the same, but why i can do it? i mean when Dx=0 i am using x like using in standart bases

Comment: When solving $Dx=0,$ you find the coordinates $x$ of your vectors $v\in\ker T$ in the basis $B.$ It is then easy to calculate the coordinates of $v$ in the standard basis.

Comment: sorry i dont get it, as i descibed x is already in standard coordinates instead of basis B. so instead solving D[v]=0 'as should be'  they solving Dx=0 when x in standard basis.(1,x,x^2)

Comment: Oh, may be the misunderstanding comes from a conflict of notations! Their $x$ in $Dx=0$ does not denote the second vector $x$ of the standard basis $(1,x,x^2),$ but rather an arbitrary column matrix $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: as i understand when Dx=0 it says x in standad form like using  standard basis.(1,x,x^2) .
but i dont understand why i can do it

Comment: No, with the notations of my *first* explanation above, $v=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$ where $(e_1,e_2,e_3)=B,$ not the standard basis.

Comment: ok the x represent arbitrary column matrix, so i am trying to understand how its not affect the result, i mean after solving using arbitrary column, what it tell me compared to solving in vector coordinates to the general vector. i dont know why i missed the point of it. also e1,e2,e3 represent in my books the standard bases depending on the vector space we are working on. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: ..as above, i still missed the point how using arbitrary column matrix to find the basis, not affect the result. maybe its from lack of knowledge. i mean because we are using  representation matrix that Leaning on B, and instead solving D[v]=0, we solve Dx=0 and its no affect the result, i missed somthing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I intentionnaly won't use the letters $a,b,c$ because they denote two different things in your post.)

Let
$$(e_1,e_2,e_3)=(1,x,x^2)\text{ and }(e'_1,e'_2,e'_3)=B.$$
The image by $T$ of a vector
$$v=x_1e'_1+x_2e'_2+x_3e'_3$$
is $T(v)=y_1e'_1+y_2e'_2+y_3e'_3$ where $\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3\end{pmatrix}=D\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\end{pmatrix}.$

So,
$$\begin{align}v\in\ker T&\iff D\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\&\iff x_1=x_2=-x_3\\&\iff\exists\lambda\in\Bbb R\quad v=\lambda(e'_1+e'_2-e'_3)\\&\iff\exists\lambda\in\Bbb R\quad v=2\lambda e_1.
\end{align}$$

This was your book's solution. Your method gives the same final result but with a little  more effort: if the same vector $v$ is written a priori

$$v:=v_1e_1+v_2e_2+v_3e_3$$
then, as you found:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\end{pmatrix}=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}v_1+v_2-v_3\\ v_1-v_2+v_3\\-v_1+v_2+v_3\end{pmatrix}$$
so
$$\begin{align}v\in\ker T&\iff D\begin{pmatrix}v_1+v_2-v_3\\ v_1-v_2+v_3\\-v_1+v_2+v_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\&\iff v_2=v_3=0\\&\iff\exists\lambda\in\Bbb R\quad v=2\lambda e_1.
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you for your kind help, much appreciated!